# Home made board game, called Catfish Lake, where I have created a multiplication like grid table to create "new make believe" Crystal Catfish

Tags: components

The system I use now is kinda complicated, in that I have three sheets of paper needed to create a new species of Catfish.  The first sheet has a list of 100 gems.  The second sheet is a code, where each letter of the alphabet is given a number.  The number is then assigned to either a column, or row, where each column, and row are given characteristics, to combine with column... so anywho... is there an easier way?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest simplification I can think of would be to use letters to label your rows/columns, which would remove converting from a letter to a number, and would instead provide letters -> characteristics on a single sheet.

I do have a few questions about the game, but not enough reputation to post comments.  Where do the letters come from?  Also, is the list of 100 gems coming as a result of the multiplication?  How do you determine which numbers to multiply?  Additional details on how the game is played would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, my mind wanders.  Answer to first question, Zaren, The letters are picked from any text.  Multiplication has nothing to do with the combining of characteristics, in columns to characteristics in rows.  Example: Say I have in Column #1 labeled Beryl, and in row # 5 a characteristic called " White Striped".  The text are assigned single digit numbers 0-9.  With the above Column and row #'s chosen by text, I would get a " White Striped Beryl Catfish".  Did this answer your question?  And Thanks for responding.

Comment: So in the example column 1 is always Beryl, and row 5 is always "White Striped"?  So if I had column 2, row 5 I'd have a White Striped <2> Catfish?  Also, would it be possible to provide an image of the sheets?

Comment: Answer to first question: Yes.  Answer to second question:  Each Column would have a different gem name, for the species of Catfish.  Each row a different pattern and color for the combining with the columns.  Answer to third question, No.  I am using a library Computer, and have no money to scan, or copy my journal, and wouldn't want to go through the trouble.  thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, I agree with using letters over the converting, to #.  The purpose of using numbers is multifunctional, in that I can also use them for values.

Comment: Could you walk through an example of a players turn?  It's still not clear how all of the sheets are used, though I do understand the characteristic sheet better now.  Also, I'd recommend adding the additional information about the game into the original question so it's easier to find for others.  It's also typically best to let a question sit for a couple days so hopefully get additional answers.